# How align text of form to the right side in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a Windows Form Application. I want to Align the Text to  Right of Title Bar of Form. I set RightToLeft property to Yes, it worked in design time but didn't work in run time.

How can I do it? I don't want to set RightToleftLayout to True.

Comment: Do you really have to?  The Form title is the domain of Wiindows, not of your app. My advice: just leave it be.

Comment: I would advice to include some code into your question. It will increase the chances of receiving an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a function or something of visual studio who can lead you to do this.

The title bar of winforms is a native application of Windows, so it's not a good idea to move things on it.

But if you really want to do that, or you really need to, you can do something like this:

```
this.Text = "                                                   " + this.Text;
```

And modify any way you want.

Comment: thank you, but if the size of form changed because of desktop resolution, it does not work correctly.

Comment: That's why you don't should move the components of Windows. That's a good way if your form is static, or if your form is set as FormBorderStyle as Fixed3D or FixedSingle for example.